# What is the best way to have timeout triggers in nodejs ? for example I want to cancel order if no drivers accepts in certain time

Tags: node.js, triggers, event-handling, settimeout

I am building an application similar to uber so I want to have timeout callbacks, Where when a new request comes in I want to keep track of the order and cancel the order after certain time if no drivers accepts the order. I have planned to use setTimeout in nodejs for now, Is there any better way to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I assume the proper solution would be:

1. accept the request.
2. store it inside the DB with the status `pending`.
3. return the response to the client.
4. in another process or worker search for the requests inside the DB and dispatch them to the drivers, if any driver accepts that request, change the status `accepted`.
5. in the meanwhile, you need to have another endpoint to return job status and etc, client use this for checking for job status for let's say 1 minute, and pulls the result every 2 seconds.
6. Inside the worker just update the request to status `canceled` if they passed the threshold.

Comment: but it will become a polling mechanism from the client right? I don't want to depend on the client, it should happen on the server side.

Comment: No it doesn't have to be, you can change the fifth stage with socket.io and push the result to the client instead of making the client pull the result https://socket.io/

Comment: I am doing exactly what you have put in 6 steps, using gcp pubsub to queue the requests between different microservices. But instead of socket mechanism which again would be using setInterval inside callback, I am planning to go for setTimeout which checks for the request state after specified time and cancel the request if it is still waiting and refund the money. Just wanted to check if there is any better mechanism to achieve timed callbacks in nodejs. Thanks for your suggestions

Comment: I see, so I guess that would be not a good idea to use setTimeout, consider your process crashes, then all the requests will be automatically dropped, instead, it would be wise to use cronjob instead or if you are using K8S, use Kube scheduler

Comment: Yes probably I will use cronjob as a backup mechanism, running every 2 mins once to check which all orders are waiting for more than specified mins and cancelling all of them. For Now I have not found any better mechanism than setTimout programatically.

Comment: you don't need the timeout if you have cronjob

Comment: I will use timeout as main mechanism and cronjob as backup mechanism which runs periodically as a cloud function outside the microservice so if one fails other will keep checking periodically for possible glitches. Imagine having 100 of order to be cancelled by cronjob running through the loop from sql query it is time consuming task to cancel each and every order one by one, so setTimeout will cancel the order individually without having to go through the loop.

Comment: you don't have to do so, the cronjob is a single update query to change the status for all jobs passed some threshold, the dispatcher part retrieve the jobs sends the job to  each driver  once, then either driver accept that or it would be canceled automatically by cronjob

Comment: No updating database is just a part, there are notifications that needs to be dispatched, refunding process needs to be initiated for this to happen for all orders at once it can't be a single query but a loop of orders from that query which needs to be sent to another micro service to do all this process again.

Comment: No, all the works that you mentioned need to be dispatched into the broker like Rabbitmq and then multiple microservices listen  to that  and do the job, it's a bad idea to send them one by one to other services

Comment: you will emit job_canceled  and then each service that is interested in that event process the required job(finance and etc)

Comment: Ya I got what you are saying, I will research a little bit more on this problem and decide. Thanks for suggestion :)

Comment: sure, let me know I can help you with any, and if the answer was helpful, please accept that,
much obliged